# Append dynamic arrays

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two cells that are the result of formulas that produce dynamic arrays. I want to combine them into a longer array. For example, consider:

```
List1 | List 2
a | a
b | c
c | d
```

and then the following formulas:

```
List 1 and not List 2 | List 2 and not List 1
=FILTER(Table1[List1],NOT(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Table1[List1],Table1[List2])))) | =FILTER(Table1[List2],NOT(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Table1[List2],Table1[List1]))))
```

which produces:

```
List 1 and not List 2 | List 2 and not List 1
b | d
```

What I want now is a cell that produces another dynamic array from those results that is:

```
Only one list
b
d
```

It seems like this does what I'm looking for (adapted from https://exceljet.net/formula/combine-ranges) (where C10# is the result under '    List 1 and not List 2' and D10# is the result under 'List 2 and not List 1):

```
=LET(rows1,ROWS(C10#),rows2,ROWS(D10#),cols1,COLUMNS(C10#),rowindex,SEQUENCE(rows1+rows2),colindex,SEQUENCE(1,cols1),IF(rowindex<=rows1, INDEX(C10#,rowindex,colindex),  INDEX(D10#,rowindex-rows1,colindex)))
```

But this seems crazy! My understanding is that with Google Sheets one can simply do:

```
{Range1;namedRange2}
```

So I'm hoping there is something similar in Excel...

Comment: Nope, there is no shortcut here.  There are things Excel does that Google sheets doesn't and things Google sheets does that Excel doesn't.

Comment: The equivalent for {Range1;namedRange2} in Excel 365 is VSTACK, I think. Is that what you need - i.e. VSTACK the two output columns as your new output?

Answer (score 0):

With Excel 365
`=VSTACK(C10#,D10#)`